# WPF Control Style of Button not detecting IsMouseOver

Tags: wpf, xaml

So I am trying to create button style (background opacity to black with 20% alpha and default colour of text changes to clear white) with using `ResourceDictionary`. I do include file into `App.xaml` like:

```
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="Style/ButtonStyles.xaml"/>
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>
```

and to button I am applying `x:Key`, `Style="{StaticResource TopBarButtons}"`

So my style of it looks like (random colours just to test):

```
    <Style x:Key="TopBarButtons" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="HotPink"></Setter>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                    <Border CornerRadius="5" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" BorderThickness="1" Padding="5">
                        <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                    </Border>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red" />
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Lime" />
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
```

But none of those are detecting, nothing change at all.. What's my error?

Comment: I recretated this with a basic wpf app and it's working, can you provide more informations about this issue please?

Comment: Hmm.. Maybe I'll show my button: `<Button Style="{StaticResource TopBarButtons}" x:Name="Exit" Content="✖" Width="auto" Height="32px" Grid.Column="1" Background="Transparent" BorderBrush="Transparent" FontSize="9"/>`

Comment: The property values set directly on the Button have higher precedence than any values set by Style Setters.

Comment: @Clemens has right. After copying and hovering over it, only the foreground of my button changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting

```
<Button ... Background="Transparent"/>
```

directly on the Button sets a so-called *local value*, which takes higher precedence than a value set by a Style Setter or a Setter in a Style Trigger.

Any value that should be changed by a Style Trigger can only be initialized by a Style Setter, e.g.

```
<Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
```

For reference, see [Dependency property value precedence](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/properties/dependency-property-value-precedence?view=netdesktop-6.0).